# how to find/count role from an array of mongo document of role where effective to is null and role is Technician

Tags: arrays, mongodb

how to find/count role from an array of mongo document of role where effective to is null and role is Technician

```
"Roles" : [ 
        {
            "Role" : "Circle Manager",
            "Effective From" : "10-Jan-2017",
            "Effective To" : "10-Nov-2017"
        }, 
        {
            "Role" : "Technician",
            "Effective From" : "10-Jan-2017",
            "Effective To" : ""
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi Rahul and welcome to the site! It would be great if you could provide a bit of context to your question. Please tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to get the desired result. You can also check for a working example at http://skillcram.com/MongoDB.htm

db.roles.find({"Role" : "Technician","Effective To" : ""})

Comment: db.Users.find( { "Roles.Role": { $exists: true ,"$in" : ["Technician"]} ,"Roles.Effective To": {$eq : null}},{"Roles.Role":1})                                        above code is not working but when i removed $eq condition and using $ne , it will return the record but effective to is not null in case only circle manager .... can anyone help